# how to provide css property in different element of form?

Tags: css

I have two forms in my html page. Both of the forms contain `input type="text"`  property.

How can I give different css for both the input type text?

If I apply this:

```
input[type=text] {
   //style
}
```

it will change style for both the element of form.

Answer (score 0):

You could give each input it's own Id or class selector and style the Ids respectively.

```
<input id='input1'> </input>
<input id='input2'> </input>

<style> 
#input1 {
-- insert styles here for input 1
}

#input2 {
-- insert styles here for input 2
}
</style>
```

You can also achieve your desired result by creating an inline style (Quick and dirty).

```
<input style="style1:theStyle;"> </input>
<input style="style2:theStyle;"> </input>
```

In the future please share a code snippet and be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

for this I think you have any container around this input[type=text] tags . so you can use this container as reference and point to that both input tags.

```css
.form-container input[type=text]:nth-child(1){
border:2px dashed #000;
}
.form-container input[type=text]:nth-child(2){
border:2px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <input type="text" >
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

or you can put an 'id' to input tags.

```css
#form-one{border:1px dashed #000;}
#form-two{border:1px dotted #000;}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
<input type="text" id="form-one" >
<input type="text" id="form-two">
</div>
```